# How to find element in html when the id is dynamic? My aim is to find element and select "option" under it

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

HTML:

```
<select id="XYZ_SV_12345" class="clsSelectControl pv" multiple="" size="11" aria-multiselectable="true" aria-invalid="false" style="width: auto;">
```

Here the id is dynamic but first few characters are always same i.e:"XYZ_SV_" is constant and remaining numeric values are dynamic.

I tried find element using below methods but no luck.kindly help me to find the element.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'XYZ_SV_']")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[id*="XYZ_SV_"]')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".clsSelectControl.pv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the xpath that you should use.

```
//select[starts-with(@id,'XYZ_SV_')]
```

Below is the code.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[starts-with(@id,'XYZ_SV_')]")
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

If you want to use CSS then please check the below.

```
select[id^='XYZ_SV_']
```

Below is the code

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select[id^='XYZ_SV_']")
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Replace your css selector `input[id*="XYZ_SV_"]` to `input[id^='XYZ_SV_']` , and it should work if selenium will find the unique entry in dom.

Note that `*` if for **subString** matching whereas `^` represents `start-with` .

**Code :**

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[id^='XYZ_SV_']")
```

Answer (score 0):

If contains has not worked I do not think starts with would as the id format would be similar(my assumption), if the id you are looking for is the first in the many available similar starts-with id than selenium would select that. or, you can combine the id with class to form a unique combination.

may be you can try something like

```
//select[starts-with(@id,'XYZ_SV_') and contains(@class, 'clsSelectControl')]
```

If this does not work. you should go for ancestors till you find only one element and then traverse back to what you require. Can you add the whole Dom so that I can form the xpath.
Try to get an unique way to identify the element. you can go to parent/siblings/ancestors to get to the element you are searching.

Alpha version of selenium 4 is out you can add that and use a nearby tagname and go for above,below,toRightOf,toLeftOf,near(50pixel) methods of relativeBy.

(My suggestion is not to use selenium 4 yet on production environment till a stable final release is made, but can be tried on local environments)

Answer (score 0):

As you have pointed out that the *id* attribute is **dynamic** and the first few characters of the *id* attribute are always same i.e. "XYZ_SV_" so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select.clsSelectControl.pv[id^='XYZ_SV_']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@class='clsSelectControl pv' and starts-with(@id,'XYZ_SV_')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```